# Java negative arraysize exception when launching music with clip.open

Tags: java, javax.sound.sampled

I am currently trying to launch music into my program using `javax.sound.sampled`,
and I wrote a method called music which is supposed to launch a music clip when executed. It goes like this:

```
public void playMusic(){
    try {
        AudioInputStream astream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
                newFileInputStream("bin/ctk_tune.mp3"));    
        AudioFormat baseFormat = astream.getFormat();

        AudioFormat newFormat = new AudioFormat(
            AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
            baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
            16,
            baseFormat.getChannels(),
            baseFormat.getChannels() * 2,
            baseFormat.getSampleRate(),
            false);
    
        AudioInputStream dstream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
                newFormat, astream); 
    
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(dstream);
    
        clip.setFramePosition(0);
        clip.start();
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("music not loaded : ");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I tried running it, I got an uncaught exception (the program didn't launch) which said:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.open(PulseAudioClip.java:449)
at mainProgram.playMusic(mainProgram.java:211)
at mainProgram.<init>(mainProgram.java:67)
at Launcher.main(Launcher.java:16)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is failing when it calls this method:

```
@Override
public void open(AudioInputStream stream) 
        throws LineUnavailableException, IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) (stream.getFrameLength() * 
                                    stream.getFormat().getFrameSize())];
    stream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    open(stream.getFormat(), buffer, 0, buffer.length);
}
```

It would appear that the expression:

```
    stream.getFrameLength() * stream.getFormat().getFrameSize()
```

is giving you a negative value.  That will cause that exception ... and I cannot see any other way that the exception *could* happen in that method.

My guess is that either there is something wrong with the way you are creating the stream or format descriptor, or there is something wrong with the audio file you are trying to play.

---

I suggest you use a debugger to figure out why that expression is negative.

Comment: You were right. With a system.out.print(); I found out that both astream.getFormat() and dstream.getFormat() are egual to -1. However, I don't know why that is (my music source code is a valid music track). If anyone knows how to solve this, I would apreciate it.

Comment: Keep debugging.  If you work backwards **using a DEBUGGER**, you can find out what causes those numbers to be negative.